# Выравнивание текста, чтобы текст не наползал сверху на слайдер

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, bootstrap

Дело в том, что в Bootstrap текст лезет сверху на слайдер.
Я уже пробовал и флексы и таблицы с `col`.

Как можно поправить?

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">

                    <h1 class="offer__title justify-content-center align-items-center d-flex align-content-around flex-wrap">
                        Inspire your inspiration
                    </h1>
                    <div class="offer__intro justify-content-center ">
                        Simple to use for your app, products<br>showcase and your inspiration
                    </div>
                    <p class="offer__text justify-content-center align-items-center ">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent vitae eros eget tellus tristique bibendum. Donec rutrum sed sem quis venenatis. Proin viverra risus a eros volutpat tempor. In quis arcu et eros porta lobortis sit
                    </p>

                </div>

            </div>

           </div>
           </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">

                    <h1 class="offer__title justify-content-center align-items-center d-flex align-content-around flex-wrap">
                        Inspire your inspiration
                    </h1>
                    <div class="offer__intro justify-content-center ">
                        Simple to use for your app, products<br>showcase and your inspiration
                    </div>
                    <p class="offer__text justify-content-center align-items-center ">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent vitae eros eget tellus tristique bibendum. Donec rutrum sed sem quis venenatis. Proin viverra risus a eros volutpat tempor. In quis arcu et eros porta lobortis sit
                    </p>

                </div>

            </div>

           </div>
           </div>
```

У вас все работает, сделайте пример с полным кодом